# Simple Unit Testing - Parse Invalid Input To Throw Error C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, parsing, methods

I have a very basic method that divides two double values.
For unit testing I want to include a invalid input (string) to throw error message or exception. What is most simple way to parse the value or fail the test (expected)?

CalculatorClass.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Calculator
{
    public class CalculatorClass
    {
        //METHODS
        public double Divide(double num1, double num2)
        {
            double result = num1 / num2;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

UnitTest1.cs

```
using System;
using Calculator; //ADD REFERENCE
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace CalcMethodTest
{
    //AreEqual
    //AreNotEqual
    //AreNotSame
    //AreSame
    //Equals
    //Fail
    //Inconclusive
    //IsFalse
    //IsInstanceOfType
    //IsNotNull
    //IsNull
    //IsTrue
    //ReplaceNullChars

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void _1_3_Test_Divide_Input_Seven_2_Output_Error()
        {
            //ARRANGE
            CalculatorClass calcObj = new CalculatorClass();
            string expectedOutput = "Error - Invalid Input";
            //ACT

            //----HERE WRONG DATA TYPE FOR TESTING----
            double result = calcObj.Divide("Seven", 2);
            //ASSERT
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedOutput, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your test will not compile

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Divide` method takes input of `double,double` the `string` wrong data type you use cannot be used as input.

In order to allow the input to be `string` or number, I suggest you to change the argument type to a base class common to both (say, `object`) and then expand the `Divide` by trying to parse the data - returning `false` if the process cannot be finished (or if the exception occur, up to you), similar to `TryParse` method provided by `.Net`. You can also extend the `out` variable to include the error `string` if you find it suitable.

Also, more appropriate name would be `TryDivide` than `Divide`:

```
namespace Calculator {
  public class CalculatorClass {
    //METHODS
    public bool TryDivide(object num1, object num2, out double doubleVal, out string errorString) {
      doubleVal = 0;
      errorString = string.Empty;

      try {
        if (num1 == null || num2 == null) {
          errorString = "number(s) cannot be null";
          return false;
        }

        double num = 0, den = 0;
        bool parseResult;

        if (num1 is double)
          num = (double)num1;
        else {
          parseResult = double.TryParse(num1.ToString(), out num);
          if (!parseResult) {
            errorString = "numerator cannot be parsed as double";
            return false;
          }
        }

        if (num2 is double)
          den = (double)num2;
        else {
          parseResult = double.TryParse(num2.ToString(), out den);
          if (!parseResult) {
            errorString = "denominator cannot be parsed as double";
            return false;
          }
        }

        doubleVal = num / den;
        return true;

      } catch (Exception ex) {
        errorString = ex.ToString();
        return false; //may also be changed to throw
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Just then you will be able call your `TryDivide` with `string` input:

```
double doubleResult;
string errorString;
bool result = calcObj.TryDivide("Seven", 2, out doubleResult, out errorString);
if (!result){ //something is wrong
    Console.WriteLine(errorString);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to pass a `string` where a `double` parameter is expected. If you absolutely need to be able to pass a `string` parameter to this method, you should not expect it to fail based on it being an invalid type - only if the conversion to a `double` failed. In that case, I'd attempt some rudimentary parsing of a `string` to a `double` (however in that case you'd probably only want to parse "7", not "seven" - up to you though).

What you have written will never be able to get tested, purely because it will never compile using C#.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to test exception handling in unit tests and how you can fail tests by passing wrong arguments, look at this example.

```
public class Sum
{
    //Returns the sum of 2 positive odd integers
    //If either of arguments is even, return -1
    //If either of arguments is negative, throw exception
    public int PositiveSumOddOnly(int a, int b)
    {
        if(a < 0 || b < 0)
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("One or more of your arguments is negative");
        if(a%2 == 0 || b%2 == 0)
            return -1;
        return a + b;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class Sum_Test
{
    [TestMethod]
    public int PositiveSumOddOnly_ShouldThrowInvalidArgumentExecption(int a, int b)
    {
        Sum s = new Sum();
        try
        {
            int r = s.PositivesumOddOnly(1,-1);
        }
        catch(InvalidArgumentException e)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("One or more of your arguments is negative", e.Message);
        }
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public int PositiveSumOddOnly_ShouldReturnNegativeOne(int a, int b)
    {
        Sum s = new Sum();
        int r = s.PositiveSumOddOnly(1,2);
        Assert.AreEqual(r,-1);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public int PositiveSumOddOnly_ShouldReturnSumOfAandB(int a, int b)
    {
        Sum s = new Sum();
        int r = s.PositiveSumOddOnly(1,1);
        Assert.AreEqual(r,2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
[TestMethod]
public void _1_3_Test_Divide_Input_Seven_2_Output_Error()
{
    //ARRANGE
    CalculatorClass calcObj = new CalculatorClass();
    string expectedOutput = "Error - Invalid Input";
    //ACT
    //----CHANGED TO STRING. THEN CAST BACK TO DOUBLE INSIDE METHOD----
    string result = calcObj.Divide("Seven", "2");
    //ASSERT
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedOutput, result);
}
```

Method:

```
public string Divide(string num1, string num2)
{
    string resultMsg = "";

    try
    {
        double num1Dbl = double.Parse(num1);
        double num2Dbl = double.Parse(num2);
        double result = num1Dbl / num2Dbl;
        resultMsg = result.ToString();
        return resultMsg;
    }
    catch (FormatException error)
    {
        resultMsg = "Error - Invalid Input";
        return resultMsg;
    }
}
```